# Oracle BI Publisher, RTF Template Date format

Tags: oracle, rtf, bi-publisher

I have used "Date, MM/DD/CCYY" under the `<format>` column in the RTF, when used in SQL developer I get proper output where CC is replaced with century(e.g. 03/07/2016 as per the format "MM/DD/CCYY" will be 03/07/2116 [21st century]) but in RTF I get the output as 03/07/CC16.
I also tried TO_CHAR(FIELD,’MM/DD/CCYY’) but its not working. Can you please let me know the issue, why the format is not workin

Answer (score 0):

Try using small 'yy' instead of 'YY'.Hopefully you will get the output.

if you want to display concatenated with CC then use small yy,else you can do like this "MM/DD/CC/YY" Or "MM/DD/CCyy"

Please post if you have any other concerns.